# std::bind on a multi parameter function fails at compile time resolution in function template

Tags: c++

I have a template function:

```
template <class F>
        Real solveImpl(const F& f,
                       Real xAccuracy)
```

and I need to pass it a functor f that takes a single argument x and returns a double, basically a `std::function<Real(Real)>`. I have the following member function:

```
Real UnderlyingDefaultTimeSimulation::cumulativeHazardFunction(int
            scenarioIdx, Real t1, Real t2, Real target)
```

for which all arguments except `t2` are to be clamped down, so I went ahead and used the classic

```
auto f = std::bind(&UnderlyingDefaultTimeSimulation::cumulativeHazardFunction, j, t1, std::placeholders::_1, exponential[i]);
```

thinking that the newly created function f will effectively be a callable that takes only a single argument `t2`. When I write `solve(f, accuracy)` the compiler fails at compile time resolution after trying all possible matches with the error message:

No matching function for call to object std::_1::bind(............)

Any other way on how to turn my member function:

```
Real UnderlyingDefaultTimeSimulation::cumulativeHazardFunction(int
                scenarioIdx, Real t1, Real t2, Real target)
```

into an `std::function<Real(Real)>` after clamping all arguments except `t2`?

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind something for `*this` as well, otherwise, there's nothing to invoke the member function on. If you are in a member function already, you probably want the current object:

```cpp
auto f = std::bind(&UnderlyingDefaultTimeSimulation::cumulativeHazardFunction, *this, j, t1, std::placeholders::_1, exponential[i]);
//                                                                             ^~~~~
```

You could also use a lambda:

```cpp
auto f = [=](const Real& t2) {
    return /* this-> */ cumulativeHazardFunction(j, t1, t2, exponential[i]);
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out.